# Grails nullable on float property?

Tags: grails

I have a class that has a float property on which if I set nullable
true it won't save and gives validation errors. Can I not set nullable
on numbers? It seems to work fine for Strings.

Comment: Can you show the definition of the class in question?

Comment: Are you using "float" the primitive or "Float" the object?

Comment: There is no such thing as a null float with a lower case "f".

Comment: If he is getting null problems with a float, it has to be a Float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have nullable Float.

```
// grails-app/domain/com/demo/Product.groovy
package com.demo

class Product {
    Float nullableFloat
    Float notNullableFloat
    static constraints = {
        nullableFloat nullable: true
        notNullableFloat nullable: false
    }
}
```

The following grails shell session shows interacting with and demonstrates that nullableFloat is in fact nullable:

```
groovy:000> import com.demo.Product
===> [import com.demo.Product]
groovy:000> new Product().validate()
===> false
groovy:000> new Product(notNullableFloat: 21.12).validate()
===> true
groovy:000> new Product(nullableFloat: 21.12, notNullableFloat: 21.12).validate()
===> true
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Ok that was it. I changed from 'float' to 'Float' and now Im nullable. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote you up but I have marked the answer as correct. Thanks so much.

Comment: It does not make sense that you were having nullability problems with a primitive float. There is no such thing as a null primitive.